# How to find the minimum CDS(connected dominating set) in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I could find a minimum CDS in O(nlgn) by greedy strategy, which is to choose the vertex with the largest degree every time.
But now I need to find the minimum CDS in linear time.
Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Every vertex in graph has degree less than n. So you can sort the vertices in linear time (the simplest way is to keep n linked lists, one for degree).

Comment: @EvgenyShavlyugin how can I sort the vertices in linear time? The cost of sort will be no less than O(nlogn).

Comment: I have found a solution. The problem can be solved by dynamic programing.